# Using the correct amount of space around unit symbols

Tags: spacing, macros, units

This is from an old package I developed back in 2003.  The idea was to cover international system units (SI) and other type of units, roughly following guidelines from that document.

> Units should use some straight font (roman vs. italic or oblique), they are not abbreviations and should never use a period, and should be separated from the quantity by a space (if typographically possible by a small space) and should be separated also from following punctuation.

So I defined macro `\unit` that would typeset the following argument as `\mathrm`
handling a tinyspace `\,` before to separate it from the quantity and would add an additional tinyspace after if followed by punctuation.  It also took an optional argument for typesetting an exponent.

It also had an additional macro `\newunit` that would create a command for most common uints.

I also attempted for these commands to work both in normal text as in math-mode.

The code bellow shows the macros defined and an example:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\makeatletter
  %%% Modified from xspace
  \DeclareRobustCommand\uspace{\futurelet\@let@token\@uspace}
  \def\@uspace{%
    \ifx\@let@token\bgroup\else
    \ifx\@let@token\egroup\else
    \ifx\@let@token\/\else
    \ifx\@let@token\ \else
    \ifx\@let@token~\else
    \ifx\@let@token.\,\else
    \ifx\@let@token!\,\else
    \ifx\@let@token,\,\else
    \ifx\@let@token:\,\else
    \ifx\@let@token;\,\else
    \ifx\@let@token?\,\else
    \ifx\@let@token/\else
    \ifx\@let@token'\else
    \ifx\@let@token)\,\else
    \ifx\@let@token-\else
    \ifx\@let@token\@xobeysp\else
    \ifx\@let@token\space\else
    \ifx\@let@token\@sptoken\else
     \space
     \fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi}
  \newcommand\unit[1]{\def\@tempa{#1}\unit@}
  \newcommand\unit@[1][\@empty]{%
    \ensuremath{\,%
      \textrm{\@tempa}%
      \ifx#1\@empty\else
       ^{#1}\fi}%
    \uspace}
  \newcommand\newunit[2]{%
    \@namedef{#1}{\unit{#2}}}
  \newcommand\degree{%
    \ensuremath{^\circ}}
\makeatother
% SI official and common derivated units
\newunit{m}{m}
\newunit{kg}{kg}
\newunit{sec}{s}
\newunit{amp}{A}
\newunit{ohm}{$\Omega$}
\newunit{kelvin}{\degree K}
\newunit{celcius}{\degree C}

\begin{document}
\newunit{cm}{cm}
One inch is 2.54\cm and one square inch is 6.4516\cm[2].
\[(2.54\cm)^2=6.4516\cm[2]\]

\newunit{farenheit}{\degree F}
Water freezes at 32\farenheit and boils at 212\farenheit.
\[100\celcius=212\farenheit-32\farenheit\]

International unit system defines the Ampere (\amp) and the
second (\sec), however it does ot define the Culomb (\unit{C})
prefering the compund Ampere-second (\amp\sec).
(Although it should look as \unit{As}.)
\[1\unit{C} = 1\amp\sec = 1\unit{As}.\]

If a tension of 12\unit{V} on a resistor of 15\ohm will produce
a current of 0.8\amp.
\[\frac{12\unit{V}}{15\ohm}=0.8\amp\]

The gravitational field on Eath's surface is 1\unit{g}, and this
is roughly equal to 9.8\unit{N}/\kg or 32\unit{ft}/\sec[2].
\[1\unit{g} \simeq 9.8\frac{\unit{N}}{\kg}
 = 9.8\m\sec[-2] \simeq 32\frac{\unit{ft}}{\sec[2]}\]

\end{document}
```

[image: Example output]

In most running text and and math mode it works fine, however the output sometimes leaves spaces too wide where no space should be.

What kind of trick may I use to eliminate the spaces where I don't need them
while preserving the space I want?

I have noticed that command `\mathrel` handle the spaces similarly as I expect for `\unit`

(The space previous to the degree symbol might be handled apart, as it affects
all the instances of those units.)

((I got the attention that package `siunitx` might already do what I attempted; while using that package might solve my typographic problems, it doesn't solve my “I want to know how to do it” problem.))

Comment: It looks like the key question here is trying to reproduce functionality similar to the `xspace` package, _i.e_ 'auto-adding' spaces after commands. That would mean that that the units part is really not that significant other than for context. Is that correct?

Comment: Can you give a link to »that document«? Are you aware of the [siunitx](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) package?

Comment: @Johannes_B the document was printed and posted in a wall, however I think it might be this one here: http://gemini.udistrital.edu.co/comunidad/grupos/gispud/RAIZDC/contenidoprogramatico/capitulo1/ntc1000.PDF (pages enumerated 1 to 7)  I don't find, however, the part of separating units from punctuation.

Comment: @JosephWright I indeed recognize that my `\uspace` command was a rip of `\xspace` and it behaves nicely when using single units inside text (or math mode) just after a number.  It does not work as well when mentioning units in isolation or composing units.

Comment: @CarlosEugenioThompsonPinzón My point is that your code isn't just a rip of `\xspace`: try the latter in your demo and the problems go away. Side issue: unit names are not capitalised: it's 'ampere' and 'coulomb'.

Comment: @JosephWright there was a reason I derived `\uspace` from `\xspace` instead to using it.  Retested in my example and it solves none of the issues I still have, while it eliminates what I tried and succeeded to achieve.